# Java - Tromino puzzle using recursion to fill spaces

Tags: java, recursion

Im having some trouble with this Tromino program, ive got a grid filled with zero's at this point. 0 is empty space, the user defines the empty space and the size. 
Im absolutley stuck on how to divide it into easy to manage parts using recursion to fill in the other pieces. I need to make the chessboard[][] values either 1 2 3 4 to make them the correct color. Id love some help. Thanks for your time guys.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Tromino{

   public static void main( String args[]){

    //Check the command line arguments. 
      /*if(!checkArgs(args)){
         System.out.println("Invalid arguments");
         return;*/
      if (args.length == 0) {
         System.out.println("No arguments");
         return;
      } else if (args.length == 1 || args.length == 2 || args.length > 3){
         System.out.println("Invalid amount of arguments");
         return;
      } else if (!checkArgs(args)){
         System.out.println("Invalid arguments");
         return;
      } // close if

      int[] int_args = new int [3];
      for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++){
         int_args[p] = (Integer.parseInt(args[p]));   
      }//close for loop

      int size = int_args[0];
      int loc1 = int_args[1];
      int loc2 = int_args[2];

      int chessSize = (int)(Math.pow(2, size));

      //System.out.println(chessSize);

      int[][] chessBoard = new int[chessSize][chessSize];

      //printBoardGUI(chessBoard);

      //printBoard(chessBoard);
      chessBoard[loc1][loc2] = -1;

      //Solve the puzzle. Need to define a recursive method solve and call it here.
      //tileRec(size, loc1, loc2);

      //Display the board in two ways. Assume chessBoard is the 2D array.
      //printBoard(chessBoard);
      printBoardGUI(chessBoard);
   }

   /**
     * Check if the string is a valid number format.
     * @param s
     * @return True if s is a valid double.
    * a ready-to-use method
     */
   public static boolean isNumber(String s) { 
      System.out.println("is number"); 
      return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
   } 

    /**
     * Check for the required command line arguments.
     * @param args - The command line args.
     * @return True if required command line args are present and valid.
    * need to complete
     */
   public static boolean checkArgs(String[] args){ 

      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

         if (isNumber(args[i]) == false){
            System.out.println("is number returnsing false");
            return false;
         }
      }
      int[] int_args = new int [3];
      for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++){
         int_args[p] = (Integer.parseInt(args[p]));
      }//close for loop
      int validargs = 0;

      if (int_args[0] <= 5 && int_args[0] >= 1){
         validargs++;
         System.out.println("position 0 is valid");

         for(int j = 1; j <= 2; j++){   
            if ((int_args[j] >= 0) && (int_args[j] <= (Math.pow(2, (int_args[0]))-1))){ 
               System.out.println("position " + j + " is valid");
               validargs++;
            }//close inner if
         }//close for loop
      }//close outer if

      if (validargs == 3){
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }//close if/else
   } //close checkArgs


   //solveTromino
   /*public static int solveTromino(int[][] chessboard, int loc1, int loc2, int size){

      //base case
      if (size == 2){
         chessboard[loc1 - 1][loc2 -1] = 3;


      }//close if
      //recurive case
      else if (size > 2){

         int[][] quadrant = [size/2][size/2];






         //divide board into quadrants

         //send solveTromino next quadrant

      }//close else


   }//close solveTromino*/


    /**
     * An utility method of finding the mid-point of a sub-board of 2^n x 2^n
     * @param n, k. k is the row (or column) index of a given cell
     * @return the row (or column) index of the mid-point of the sub-board
    * a ready-to-use method
     */

  /* public static int getIndex(int n, int k){
      return (int)  (Math.pow(2, n-1) - 1 +(int) (k/Math.pow(2, n)) * Math.pow(2,n));
   } 

   /**
     * Draw Board using print.
     * @param chessBoard
    * a ready-to-use method
     */
   /*public static void printBoard(int[][] board){
      int boardLength = board.length;

      for(int i=0; i<boardLength; i++){
         System.out.print(" ");
         for(int j=0; j<boardLength; j++){
            System.out.print("----"); 
         }
         System.out.println();
         for(int j=0; j<boardLength; j++){
            System.out.print(" | " + board[i][j]); 
         }
         System.out.println(" |");
      }
      System.out.print(" ");
      for(int j=0; j<boardLength; j++){
         System.out.print("----"); 
      } 
      System.out.println();
   }*/


    /**
     * Display Board in GUI.
     * @param chessBoard
    * a ready-to-use method
     */

    public static void printBoardGUI(int[][] board){
       int boardLength = board.length;
       int width = 50;
       int boardLengthPx = boardLength * width;
       Hashtable<Integer, Color> colors = new Hashtable<Integer, Color>();
       DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(boardLengthPx, boardLengthPx);
       panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

       colors.put(0, Color.white);
       colors.put(1, Color.red);
       colors.put(2, Color.blue);
       colors.put(3, Color.green);
       colors.put(4, Color.magenta);

       Graphics newPanel = panel.getGraphics();
       for(int i = 0; i < boardLength; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j < boardLength; j++) {
             newPanel.setColor((Color)colors.get(board[j][i]));             
             newPanel.fillRect(j * width, i * width, width, width);
          }
       }
    }

    /**
     * Display Board GUI.
     * @param solved tromino board
     */
    /*public static void printBoardGUI(int[][] board){
        int boardLength = board.length;
        int width = 50;
        int boardLengthPx = boardLength * width;
        Hashtable<Integer, Color> colors = new Hashtable<Integer, Color>();
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(boardLengthPx, boardLengthPx);
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

        colors.put(0, Color.white);

        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        for(int i = 0; i < boardLength; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < boardLength; j++) {
                if (!colors.containsKey(board[i][j])){
                    colors.put(board[i][j],
                                                   Color.getHSBColor((float)Math.random(),
                                                                     (float)(.4 + Math.random()*0.6),
                                                                     (float)(.2 + Math.random()*0.8)));
                }
                g.setColor((Color)colors.get(board[i][j]));             
                g.fillRect(j * width, i * width, width, width);
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                g.drawLine(j * width, i * width, j * width, (i * width) + width);
                g.drawLine(j * width, i * width, (j * width) + width, i * width);
            }
        }
    }*/

}//close public class
```

Comment: I'm just reviewing your question: can you narrow down the lines of code where you are having problems dealing with it?

Comment: Starting at the comment // solveTromino, this is the method that should have recursion in it. I wrote out what i think the base case should be, but im not 100% on that or the recursion statement. the code after that is working printing statments for the basic grid and a graphics grid.